one-to-many: JPA generates wrong FK while using ddl-auto=create-drop
It seems that I made a mistake somewhere but I can not see where.
JPA insists on generating a unique constraint on a FK of one-to-many relationship on the child side. This constraint prevents me from inserting more than one record in the child table.
Parent entity:
@Entity
@Table(name = "customer")
@Data
public class CustomerDto {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    ...

    @Column(name = "notes")
    private String notes;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "customer_id")
    private List<EmailDto> emails = new ArrayList<>();

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "customer_id")
    private List<PhoneDto> phones = new ArrayList<>();
}

Child 1:
@Entity
@Table(name = "email")
@Data
public class EmailDto {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "email", unique = true, length = 128)
    private String email;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private CustomerDto customer;
}

Child 2:
@Entity
@Table(name = "phone")
@Data
public class PhoneDto {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "phone_number", nullable = false, length = 32)
    private String phoneNumber;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private CustomerDto customer;
}

The tables looks as I expect:

But this also generates an extra constraint for the foreign-key on the phone side:

The email table looks ok:

The unique constraint that Hibernate generates on the phone side ONLY allows me to insert ONE record per customer. If I try to insert two phone numbers I get a duplicate key value violates unique constraint "phone_customer_id_key" error.
If I change the JoinColumn definition on the CustomerDto.java this way:
@JoinColumn(name = "customer_id") ---> @JoinColumn(name = "customer_idx")
then it works and I can save 0..* phone numbers per customer properly.
But, this modification generates a stupid table structure:

What I am missing here?
I can create a proper structure with simple SQLs and use customer_id as a foreign key in the child tables. But why JPA generate an extra unexpected constraint?
---------- UPDATE ----------
I also tried the same before I posted this question, but the result was not as I expected. I changed again the JPA annotations as per the sugestions and I got this:

JPA does not set the foreign keys in the child table.

The following settings provides me the expected DB structure:
@Entity
@Table(name = "customer")
@Data
public class CustomerDto {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "customer-id-sequence")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "customer-id-sequence", sequenceName = "customer_id_seq", allocationSize = 1)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;


    ...
    ...

    @Column(name = "notes")
    private String notes;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "customer_id")
    private List<EmailDto> emails = new ArrayList<>();

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "customer_id")
    private List<PhoneDto> phones = new ArrayList<>();
}

Child:
@Entity
@Table(name = "email")
@Data
public class EmailDto {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "email-id-sequence")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "email-id-sequence", sequenceName = "email_id_seq", allocationSize = 1)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "email", unique = true, length = 128)
    private String email;

    @ManyToOne()
    private CustomerDto customer;
}


my suggestion - enable show-sql setting and check which real SQL statements are generated

The @JoinColumn annotation specifies the foreign key column in the database table.
So you need to move the @JoinColumn annotation from your parent dto to your child dtos like this:
Parent entity:
@Entity
@Table(name = "customer")
@Data
public class CustomerDto {
    @Id
    private Long id;

...

@Column(name = "notes")
private String notes;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private List<EmailDto> emails = new ArrayList<>();

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private List<PhoneDto> phones = new ArrayList<>();
}

Child 1:
@Entity
@Table(name = "email")
@Data
public class EmailDto {
    @Id
    private Long id;

@Column(name = "email", unique = true, length = 128)
private String email;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "customer_id")
private CustomerDto customer;
}

Child 2:
@Entity
@Table(name = "phone")
@Data
public class PhoneDto {
    @Id
    private Long id;

@Column(name = "phone_number", nullable = false, length = 32)
private String phoneNumber;

@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "customer_id")
private CustomerDto customer;
}


I suggest mappedBy attribute (in CustomerDto) to define the referencing side (non-owning side) of the relationship.

Read more: https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-joincolumn-vs-mappedby

PS.
Why Dto extension? It is used to another objects, used to transmit data between different applications or parts of the same application (could have less fields and any logic / annotations etc. ). Entities without Dto ext. are basic element in ORM and fully reflect the table in the database

Read more:  https://www.baeldung.com/java-entity-vs-dto


@AndrzejWięcławski your comment matches with my answer

@catch23 - of course, but above it's not used mappedBy, wonder why :)

You did quite an awkward mapping.
To make it right the best way is to make mapping at the child side and use mappedBy for the parent entity.
Few notices:

don't need to write fetch = FetchType.LAZY because it is the default.
it is not a bad idea to add additional utility methods for setting the right relation at the parent side
you need a default constructor without arguments for Hibernate to work
exclude setters for mapped entities collections
use DTO only for transfer objects not for entities

Finally, the parent side will look like:
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "customer")
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Customer {
    // omitted
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "customer", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @Setter(AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
    private List<Email> emails = new ArrayList<>();

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "customer", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @Setter(AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
    private List<Phone> phones = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addEmail(EmailDto email) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(email)
        email.setCustomer(this);
        emails.add(email);
    }
    // omitted the same logic for Phone
}

The child side will look like this:
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "email")
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Email {
    // omitted
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "customer_id")
    private Customer customer;
}

The second one:
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "phone")
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Phone {
    // omitted
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "customer_id", 
        foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "phone_customer_id_fk"))
    private Customer customer;
}

The second example has named foreign key programmatically. It isn't necessary, Hibernate will generate it automatically. But it gives more control over final mapping at the DB level.

Actually my entity class has noarg constructor. As I know if I don't have any other constructors, java automatically generates it. The Lombok @Data contains the @RequiredArgConstructor. I have no any private final fields so constructor is created automatically. If I have private final fields then I need the @NoArgsConstructor annotation.

Indead, ny naming with the Dao suffix is wrong, thx for this hint.

I checked the JPA specification and I confirm that FetchType.LAZY is redundant on ...ToMany relationship because this is the default. According to the spacification these are the default settings: OneToMany: LAZY, ManyToOne: EAGER, ManyToMany: LAZY, OneToOne: EAGER.
